# I have to put a second coat of Sheetrock joint compound on a patch job, do I need to wet the first coat?

Tags: drywall-mud

I had to patch a cat door that was cut into the drywall, and put in a cutout that left small gaps around the perimeter. When I applied the first coat of joint compound, it pulled into the gap in certain places, so I have to apply a second coat. Do I or should I wet the first coat before applying the second?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You shouldn't have to wet the first coat.

Comment: Rather the opposite - be sure the first coat is **fully dry** before applying the next one. "Mud" (joint compound) is not mortar.